# Is the Aviator costume special in any way?

Tags: run-sackboy-run

The Aviator costume is that last costume listed in *Run Sackboy! Run!* and is the only one that needs to be bought with the special 'Aviator Token' currency instead of normal bubbles.

The game  doesn't seem to provide any more information on it, other than it provides a +12 multiplier, which is the highest in the game. But it's not *much* higher than the next one down, which is +10.

Considering there is an entirely separate currency around this costume, is it special in any other way? Does it provide any additional bonuses or anything like that? Or is it just there to justify the 'premium' Aviator Token currency?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After getting lucky with a few golden chests I managed to accumulate the 500 Aviator Tokens needed to unlock the Aviator costume. You do indeed get a fairly large score multiplier but other than that there is no real difference - it's just another costume.